# Regex multiple occurrences of text between tags

Tags: c#, regex

I need to get a string consisting only of the text ***between*** a pair of defined tags and also a string consisting of the text ***including*** the tags. Since the text resides inside HTML **`<p>`** tags the **<** and **>** are interpreted like `&lt;` and `&gt;` (which as far as I know makes it impossible to use a Parser like the HTML Agility Pack)

So the input string looks like this:

```
Text outside of tags
&lt;internal&gt;    First occurance of text inside of tags    &lt;/internal&gt;
More text outside of tags
&lt;internal&gt;    Second occurance     &lt;/internal&gt;
```

I'm using the following code right now but it only gets the first occurance and not the second one:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(&lt;internal&gt;(.*?)&lt;/internal&gt;)", RegexOptions.Singleline);
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(inputString);

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    string outerMatch = match.Groups[1].Value;
    string innerMatch = match.Groups[2].Value;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, the code actually works. The reason it didn't pick up the second occurance was that the editor that is creating the documents inserted  and  tags for the text inside of the tags in some cases, which made the regex fail to match it. I changed the regex to this:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(&lt;.*?internal.*?&gt;(.*?)&lt;.*?/.*?internal.*?&gt;)", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Again the question like this.

Do not use regualr expression for tags identification. 
Regular expressions are stateless  and can not operate *correctly* with HTML or XML. You need to use a Parser for this.

Use [Agility pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) fot HTML parsing.

Comment: Are you sure I can do this? I tried using the HTML Agility Pack, but since the `<` and `>` are interpreted as their entity numbers ´&lt;´ and ´&gt;´ it wasn't able to catch these tags..

Comment: @ChristerWilliamPersson: if you use XML, use appropriate library for working with it.

Comment: I'm actually using the HTML agility pack to get the inner text. But this text is interpreted as text and not nodes, hence the entity numbers and thus rendering the use of a parser for the rest of the operation impossible/harder i guess

Answer (score -1):

use `\<` and `\>` instead of `&lt;` and `&gt;`

like this:

```
(\<internal\>(.*?)\</internal\>)
```

Comment: Angle brackets are no regex metacharacters and don't need to be escaped.

Comment: Your code in my system works successfully (WindowsPhone7.1). Are you using `System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Singleline`?

Comment: @Ria Is it really catching both occurances? Indeed I am using the Singleline option (it is also seen in my code above)

Comment: *@Christer William Persson* Yes. catch both occurrences.